# Javascript URL redirect

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a mock up version of google censorship for history class. I'm trying to modify the redirect url so I can put my own terms into the url:

```
function searchCensor() 
{
var keyTerms = document.getElementById("search").value;
if(keyTerms == "censorship")
    window.location = "http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/history/censor.php";
else
    window.location = "https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q="+keyTerms+"&oq="+keyTerms+"&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.851563l851824l0l851964l3l3l0l0l0l0l171l359l1j2l3l0.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=bb242dc4ab43ba95&biw=1920&bih=963"
}
```

in the else block, I try to insert keyTerms into the URL, but I end up with undefined when the search begins. Any suggestions? Here is the URL for the website: http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/history/

Comment: id's have to be unique. You have the same id (search) on your page twice.

Answer (score 1):

The "Search" link on the top bar of the same page has the same id of `search`, thus when you do your `document.getElementById('search')`, javascript returns the first element in the DOM with `id = search`, which is the `anchor` on the top bar instead of your input.

You can instead give a `name` attribute to your search form:

```
<form id="searchBox" name="searchForm">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" size="85"><br>        
</form>
```

And in your js

```
var keyTerms = document.searchForm.search.value;
// rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

In the header bar at the top, you have a button labeled "Search" that also has the id `"search"`. Try removing the id from that element.